# How do I change "Display Product Options In” to default to “Product Info Column""

Tags: database, design

When I create a simple product, I go to the Design tab and check "Product Info Column" in the "Display Product Options In" dropdown for each product I add. How can I make it that Magento defaults to "Product Info Column" instead of the other option?

I've already went to the database and changed the "options_container" row to the default value of "container1" in the "eav_attribute" table. The odd part is that it was already set to "container1" and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It's only in the database:
`UPDATE eav_attribute SET default_value = 'container1' WHERE attribute_code = 'options_container';`
I tested it and it's working fine. So if you changed it in the database - please flush the cache.

Comment: There must be something somewhere overriding this. It was actually already set to 'container1' and Magento still defaulted to "Block after Info Column". I changed it to 'container2' and then back to 'container1' and flushed the cache. Still no change.

Answer (score 2):

Updating `options_container` default value in `eav_attribute` table should do the trick. Keep in mind that if you are editing existing product the value will default to what is already saved on the product.

You can check like this:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = {options_container attribute id} and entity_id = {product id};
```

Comment: There must be something somewhere overriding this. It was actually already set to 'container1' and Magento still defaulted to "Block after Info Column". I changed it to 'container2' and then back to 'container1' and flushed the cache. Still no change. I'm not as advanced as some people so I apologize if this is dumb question, but where do you use this code to check?